# After pack to jar scala app doesn't work

Tags: scala, jar

I have this code (scala 2.9.1):

```
package pl.koziolekweb.scala.dsi
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.{ IMain, Results }

trait Eval {

  def eval(expresion: String): Option[Any] = {
    val interpreter = new IMain {
      override protected def parentClassLoader: ClassLoader = App.getClass.getClassLoader
    }
    val res = new ResultSet
    interpreter.beQuietDuring {
      interpreter.bind("res", res.getClass.getCanonicalName, res)
      interpreter.interpret("res.value = " + expresion)
    } match {
      case Results.Success => Option(res.value)
      case _ => None;
    }

  }
}


object App extends Eval {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    { eval(args(0)) } match {
      case None => println("nie bangla")
      case Some(x) => println(x)
    }
  }

}

class ResultSet {

  var value : Any  = null

}
```

when I compile it (maven)and run just call:

```
scala pl.koziolekweb.scala.dsi.App 1+1
```

program works fine (print 2). But after pack all of class files to jar and try to run

```
scala myapp.jar 1+1
```

i get

```
<console>:5: error: not found: value pl
  var value: pl.koziolekweb.scala.dsi.ResultSet = _
             ^
<console>:6: error: not found: value pl
  def set(x: Any) = value = x.asInstanceOf[pl.koziolekweb.scala.dsi.ResultSet]
                                           ^
<console>:7: error: not found: value res
       res.value = 1+1
       ^
nie bangla
```

Why? any suggestions?

//edit:

I find reason. interpreter doesn't have `myapp.jar` in classpath. How to load that jar to IMain?

Answer (score 1):

Since your username is `Koziolek`, and the failing identifier is `pl.koziolekweb.scala.dsi.ResultSet`, it has to be something in your responsibility.

I don't see an import for `ResultSet`, so I guess that pl.koziolekweb.scala.dsi is the package of App and Eval too. But I don't see a package-declaration.

But you call it with

```
scala my.pack.App 1+1
```

Is this a simplification for us? But it is in contradiction to the errormessage, so it's not a simplification, but a source of confusion.

Comment: I miss package declaration while copy code :) So now is correct.